# Which metric to use for imbalanced data in TensorFlow/Keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow, metric

I am doing a binary classification task with Keras and my model directly outputs either 0 or 1. Typically I compile the model like something below:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The dataset I have is imbalanced, only ~10% of samples are positive. I am aware that in this case accuracy is not a good metric and I can see a 90% accuracy even if the model is the same as random guessing.

The problem is, seems Keras does not provide F1 score as an alternative in its `metrics` parameter of `compile()` method (the list of method Keras provides is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics)). What else can I pass to the `metrics` parameter so that I can have a better understanding of the model's performance during the training progress?

**EDIT1**

To make the question more complete, I included a sample model definition below:

```
input_shape = image_size + (3,)
num_classes = 2
model = Sequential([
    layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=input_shape),       
    layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides=(2, 2)),
    layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])

model.build((None,) + input_shape)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

**EDIT2**

Following @noe's answer and some posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851558/tensorflow-estimator-valueerror-logits-and-labels-must-have-the-same-shape), I can make AUC work now. A few parameters must be set correctly:

1. `layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`
2. `loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),`
3. `metrics=['AUC']`

Among them, `layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` seems to be most critical, we need to use `sigmoid()` to convert the output to a range of (0, 1) to make AUC work.

```
input_shape = image_size + (3,)
num_classes = 2
model = Sequential([
    layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=input_shape),       
    layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides=(2, 2)),
    layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.build((None,) + input_shape)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=['AUC']
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUC: Area Under the ROC Curve. Check some references: [1](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/roc-and-auc), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/260164/40048), [3](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/94654/14675).

AUC = 0.5 means the classifier is random guessing. AUC = 1 is the perfect classifier.

Comment: Hi @noe, I added a sample model to my question. My understanding is that the last layer, `layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')`, makes the model output a number--either 0 or 1 (please correct me if I am wrong). If I change metrics to `metrics=['AUC'], `TF complains: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible`. Is this related to my softmax layer? Do I need to output a vector of two probabilities to make AUC work?

Comment: For binary classification you should output a single scalar, not 2, and use the binary cross-entropy loss, not the categorical cross-entropy.

Answer (score 1):

When using AUC on strongly imbalanced datasets, if you care mainly about the accuracy on the minority class, [it's much more robust to use the AUC of the Precision-Recall (PR) curve than on the ROC curve](https://machinelearningmastery.com/roc-curves-and-precision-recall-curves-for-imbalanced-classification/).

> [One common scenario is a highly imbalanced dataset where the fraction of positive class, which we want to find (like in fraud detection), is small.](https://neptune.ai/blog/f1-score-accuracy-roc-auc-pr-auc#:%7E:text=ROC%20AUC%20vs%20PR%20AUC&text=What%20is%20different%20however%20is,and%20true%20positive%20rate%20TPR.)

Here it shows how to choose the PR curve in the [TF document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC)

```
metrics=tf.keras.metrics.AUC(curve='PR')
```

Comment: AUC-PR helps. While vanilla AUC works, its score will be higher then AUC-PR, causing the false sense that the model is performing very well (actually it performs barely better than random guess). AUC-PR can mitigate this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `AUC` does not help in scenario in which you care directly about F-score. If this is the case refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61683829/calculating-fscore-for-each-epoch-using-keras-not-batch-wise) answer.